# What exactly is a variable name in C?

Tags: c

The value of an array name is the address of the start of (zeroth element) the array; therefore, the & is not necessary.

Ex:

```
scanf("%s", string1);
```

Then what is the value of the integer or character variable names which we have to use & operator? Not addresses like array names I hope. What are they? This is confusing.

Ex:

```
scanf("%d", &number1);
```

What is number1 exactly? Is it an address too?

Comment: Don't say things like that, they are confusing. An expression of array type is converted (in most contexts) to an expression of pointer type (pointer to the array's first element).

Comment: If I ask you what is `foo`, could you tell me if it is an int, float, or something else? Why not? Do you realize the problem with your question then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What is `number1` exactly? Is it an address too?*

Based on your type modifier, `number1` is presumably an `int`, but of course we don't know that for sure because you're not telling us.  If I understand correctly what you're asking, `number1` is an integer and `&number1` is a pointer to that integer.

*Then what is the value of the integer or character variable names?*

The value of an unmodified variable name is the value of that variable.  Arrays are a special case, as you noted.  Array names are not actually variables.  Given:

```
int a[10];
int *pa;
```

you can legally do this:

```
pa = a;
```

but not this:

```
a = pa;
```

`a` is the name of an array, not a variable.

**Update:** For those who think it's weird to say that an array name is not a variable, I was practically quoting the second edition of *The C Programming Language* by Kernighan and Ritchie.  (Ritchie was the creator of C.)  Now I'll quote them directly, from page 99 of the second edition:

> A pointer is a variable, so `pa=a` and `pa++` are legal.  But an array name is not a variable; constructions like `a=pa` and `a++` are illegal.

Comment: -1 You have a weird concept of variable. Arrays are variables as other variables. Do e.g `sizeof a` and you see that `a` exists. There special type make that in most contexts they decay into a pointer to the first element. But that does not make them less a "variable".

Comment: @JensGustedt Okay, but if I have a weird concept, at least I share it with the creator of the language.  Please see my update.

Comment: OP is right.  An array is not a variable.  Each member of the array is a variable.  But an array is a constant identifier.  Upvoted.

Comment: To be more specific: Jens is confusing the generic term `type identifier` with a more specific term `variable`.  Any type idenfitier can be sizeof'd.  you can do `sizeof MyStructA;` but MyStructA is a type, not a variable.

Comment: @jstine If anything, Jens is confusing "variable" and "object". An array is, indubitably, an object. Whether it is a variable depends on the definition of variable one uses. The term is not defined in the standard, so different definitions of the term do not conflict with the standard. (And it would need to be `sizeof (type)` with parentheses, whereas `sizeof object` doesn't need them.)

Comment: I am certainly not confusing variable and object. As Daniel says, variable is nothing that has a precise definition in C, this is why I was talking of a "weird concept". For me a variable is an identifier that directly represents an object of a specific type. In that sense an array declaration declares a variable, there is an identifier and there is an object. And in that sense `a[2]` is not a variable (there is no identifier) but only an object.

Answer (score 4):

> The value of an array name is the address of the start of(zeroth element) the array

No, it isn't. It's just that arrays can *decay into* a pointer to their first element in certain conditions (when passed to a function or assigned to a pointer, for example).

> therefore, the & is not necessary. !!!!!!!

Writing 7 exclamation marks is not necessary either. Note that if `arr` is an array, then `arr` and `&arr` are **not the same at all** (as you migh assume). `arr` is of type `T [N]` where T is the type of an element in the array, and `N` is the number of elements. The type of `&arr`, however, is a "pointer-to-array-of N items of type T" (`T (*)[N]`). This difference is important (not only) because pointer arithmetic will yield in different results on a pointer-to-T and on a pointer-to-array-of-T.

> Then what is the value of the integer or character variable names which we have to use & operator? Not addresses like array names I hope.

No, not like arrays (because they are not arrays), but `&` **still is** the `addressof` operator. `&variable` gives a pointer to the `variable`, of which the type is `T *`, if the type of `variable` was `T`.

In this specific case, you claimed that `number1` was an `int`, so `&number1` is an expression of type `int *`.

Comment: Then why printf("What is your name?");
  scanf("%s", string1);        expression yields the same results for scanf(“%s”, string1); scanf(“%s”, &string1); scanf(“%s”, &string1[0]); all works!!!!!  There is no difference then. They all point to same array?

Comment: @user1939432: I didn't understand,but `string1` and `&string1[0]` are the same.

Comment: @user1939432 No, it just **seems** to work OK. In reality, it invokes **undefined behavior.**

Comment: `scanf(“%s”, &string1);` is different (and may cause seg. fault on dynamically allocated `string1`). The other two are the same. Here's why: `[0]` *dereference* the array and get the first `variable`, using `&` (`addressof`) will yield `string1`. When you understand this you'll know that you are writing to the address of `string1` in the middle-case, which is not the dynamically allocated  array.

Comment: The draft of the ANSI C standard at the back of my copy of K&R says almost the exact same thing as the OP, "If the type of an expression or subexpression is 'array of *T*', for some type *T*, then the value of the expression is a pointer to the first object in the array."  I'm failing to see where the OP is wrong...

Comment: @H2CO3 Well you do start out by telling them that they're wrong about something that they're practically quoting from the standard.

Comment: @DarshanComputing Euh, nope. Everything that's written here is correct.

Comment: @H2CO3 Then please reply to my previous comment and explain what the OP and I are misunderstanding. I believe you know C much better than I do, and I'm quite open to being shown where I'm wrong. But right now the standard and the OP seem to agree, and you haven't addressed that.

Comment: @DarshanComputing Let's see. 1. It was not me who told you that "you have a weird concept of variable". I didn't want to split hair about that either. 2. I didn't claim anything that opposes the Standard. "The value of an array name is the address of the start of (zeroth element) the array" (what the OP affirmed) is not true, the value of a name of which the type is an array, is an array, and this can be implicitly converted to a pointer. This has nothing to do with the fact that names corresponding to an array are "not variables" (which seems to be the case according to the Standard).

Comment: H2CO3's mention of `(T (*)[N])` is a C++ extension to C syntax, and I think that strongly-typed arrays (preserving the size) as parameters in functions was added in ANSI C later as well.  So to me this looks more like a C vs. C++ semantics argument, and unless both sides realize that, you'll probably both argue until the moon turns dark and still think the other is wrong.

Comment: @jstine No. This is strictly a C question. With that syntax, I was referring to the fact that a pointer-to-array is denoted using `T (*name)[N]` (and I left out the name since it's not important, nor is it part of the type).

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks.  1. I do realize that; this is a different discussion.  2. I believe you missed my first comment on this thread, 8 comments prior to the one I'm writing right now.  jstine may be correct that something was changed in a later standard.  The one I quoted was the original draft of C89.

Comment: @DarshanComputing The actual formulation in the standard is "Except when [...] an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.". If http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt is to be believed, that was already so in C89. So the committee deemed the formulation with "value of" incorrect, misleading, or in some other way inferior. The standard uses the construct "value of an expression" in a couple of other places, but it is nowhere properly defined, unfortunately.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for that. Wondering at the difference, I just looked closer and realized that what's at the back of K&R is self-described as "an interpretation of the proposed standard, not the Standard itself."  I was mistaken thinking it was the standard. Kernighan and Ritchie said it is their "attempt to convey the essentials of the standard in a smaller space ... meant for easy comprehension by programmers." How K&R word it, how the actual C89, C99, and C11 standards word it, and how the OP word it all seem consistent to me.

Comment: @DarshanComputing The problem is that "The value of an array name" is not defined in the standard. So saying it is a pointer to the array's initial element is problematic. Sticking to "is converted to a pointer to the array's initial element" is the uncontroversial thing.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, to a language lawyer or compiler writer, lack of definition in the standard is a problem. K&R explaining things to "programmers rather than compiler writers" considered it clear enough.  Sure, sticking to the uncontroversial thing avoids controversy and aids clarity.  Telling the OP that they're incorrect, however, is taking things much further, and also, to me, would mean that K&R are incorrect rather than just imprecise in their programmer-friendly interpretation of the standard.

Comment: Describing *the value of an array* as a pointer to the first element is problematic because an array is an object, and C11/3.15 describes an object as "... the contents of which can represent values". This implies that the value of an array *is* the elements it contains. The definition of *value* lies in favour of this definition of "value of an array", too: "*precise meaning of the contents of an object when interpreted as having a specific type*".

Comment: @DarshanComputing In summary, when you refer to "the value of an array", it's fairly clear that you're referring to the set of elements. Isn't it important for regular programmers to be able to communicate precisely with compiler developers, to report bugs and the like? In order to avoid confusion in that realm, it'd be a great idea to explain the difference between "value of an array" and "conversion resulting in pointer to the first element in an array".

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I see "the value of an array" the same way you do. I see "the value of an array name" as a perhaps somewhat awkward but clear enough way to say "the value my program will see when I type this name". Again, I'm all for speaking with as much clarity as possible. I'm just against telling a newbie they're wrong for not saying something in quite the same way you might. I think the OP understands the concept correctly and worded it reasonably well; nearly the same way Kernighan and Ritchie chose to.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my, you do indeed have a lot to learn about C.  But perhaps the confusion is mostly about arrays & pointers.  For *practical* purposes, an array variable is just a pointer.  Realistically, it's not -- its type is indeed an array, but it is implicitly converted to a pointer of the type it is an array of. I hope that helps.

Comment: I do like the word *converted*. It sounds so much less *dead* than *decayed*. If someone were to tell me that *my arrays are decaying*, I would crave loads of LSD!

Comment: @undefined behaviour lol! Yes, thanks.  I forgot that the real word is "decayed" because it is really a downgrading of the type, going from knowing the buffer size to not.

Answer (score 1):

See , If you declared it like:

```
int number1;
```

Then `&number1` is basically the location which will store the contents of number1.

so, when you write :

```
scanf("%d"&number1);
```

The compiler stores whatever number you input into the location specified by `&number1`.So,'&number1' 
is somewhat the address where the contents of number1 will stored.

Next time you want to use the contents of `number1`,they will be picked up from the memory location specified by `&number`.

I'd like to mention this example:

```
int a,b,c;
scanf("%d %d ",&a,&b);/*&a and &b are just locations assigned to a and b, in which we store integers*/
c=a+b;
```

At,`c=a+b`,here `a` and `b` will represent the integers you stored in the memory locations assigned to them ,but `c` will represent the memory location assigned to `c`,NOTICE:that there is no `&`operator infront of `c`,we just use `&` operator in function like `scanf` which are input/output functions defined in `stdio.h` .

When you declare `int number1;`

number1 can represent an address too,for eg:
when you write `number1=4;` here `number1` represent the memory location . because you are storing 4 into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare number1 and give it some value:

```
int number1;
number1 = 1234;
```

then `&number1` is the address of the memory location where the variable is stored. If you peek into that memory location, you will find it holds 1234, the value of the variable.

If array_of_numbers is declared as:

```
int array_of_numbers[100];
```

then the first number in the array is `array_of_numbers[0]`, the address of the first element in the array is `&array_of_numbers[0]`.

`array_of_numbers` is exactly the same thing as `&array_of_numbers[0]`.

the `scanf("%d", &number1);` expects address(es) where to put the variable(s), if you did

```
number1=1234;
scanf("%d", number1);
```

the scanf function will get whatever number it parses for %d, and try to stuff it into memory location 1234, which is not what you normally want.